# Paste hex bytes into IDA Pro Hex View

Tags: ida, python, idapython, hex, memory

Is it possible to paste a series of bytes into hex view of IDA? Say I have a large buffer I need to fill with a specific value, and I have it in the form most hex editors output... 0A AB EF FF 00 01... is there some quick way to write this value to a segment of the hex view? Or do this through IDAPython?

**Edit:**

Solved using PatchByte as suggested below:

```
def PatchArr(dest, str):
  for i, c in enumerate(str):
    idc.PatchByte(dest+i, ord(c));

# usage: patchArr(start address, string of bytes to write)
patchArr(0xCAFEBABE, "\x01\x02\x03")
```

Note that I am not a fan of edits to volatile debug memory causing IDA to complain about the IDB being patched post-debug...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While in IDA's Hex View you can go to **Edit->Patch Program->Change Byte**, but I think this only lets you patch 16 bytes at a time. If you need to patch more bytes than that you can use IDAPython's **idc.PatchByte** / **idc.PatchWord** / **idc.PatchDword** to change bytes in the IDA database.

EDIT:

Just a quick note, if you want your patches applied to the original file that you loaded into IDA, you need to go to **Edit->Patch Program->Apply patches to input file** after you patch the bytes in the idb.

Comment: Thanks! Got a python solution working thanks to this. Of course changing single bytes by hand is way too slow, was the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

Below are two functions from [fwrapper](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander_Hanel/fwrapper/src/) that give examples on how to patch IDBs and import data from a file. I'd recommend checking out the code. I use it all the time for samples that decodes/decrypts data or when I have to manually dump a block of memory and patch an IDB.

```
def patch(self, temp = None):
    '''patch idb with data in fwrapper.buffer'''
    if temp != None:
            self.buffer = temp
    for index, byte in enumerate(self.buffer):
         PatchByte(self.start+index, ord(byte))

def importb(self):
    '''import file to save to buffer'''
    fileName = AskFile(0, "*.*", 'Import File')
    try:
        self.buffer = open(fileName, 'rb').read()
    except:
        sys.stdout.write('ERROR: Cannot access file')
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though this has been answered, IDA is meant as a debugger. Not as a patching tool, this has to do a lot with how IDA stores works. IDA creates a database file that allows you to remove the exe after loading it first. This can be really useful when you work with intellectual property / malware. I would recommend to use ImmDBG for your patching needs.

Comment: Is that a typo? You mean to say that IDA is not meant as a debugger, right? Of course not, it IS meant to interface with various debuggers. IDA not being able to understand a memory segment is unimportant/patching should not be stored in the IDB is a legitimate bug. ImmDBG is a completely seperate use case, and the platforms it supports are very limited in comparison.

Comment: Indeed I am sorry, it is more a brainfart then anything else. The most important thing I meant to say is that IDA is a tool you need to analyse software not crack it.